# Неправильное срабатывание функции

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var asasa = 0;
  </script>
  <table border='1px' width='500px' height='500px' align="center">
    <tr>
      <td id='tables1' class="one" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99'; player_turn(); asasa=1"></td>
      <td id='tables2' class="two" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99'; player_turn(); asasa=2"></td>
      <td id='tables3' class="three" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99'; player_turn(); asasa=3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style='border-color: red'>
      <td id='tables4' class="four" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99'; player_turn(); asasa=4"></td>
      <td id='tables5' class="five" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99'; player_turn(); asasa=5"></td>
      <td id='tables6' class="six" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99'; player_turn(); asasa=6"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style='border-color: red'>
      <td id='tables7' class="seven" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99'; player_turn(); asasa=7"></td>
      <td id='tables8' class="eight" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99'; player_turn(); asasa=8"></td>
      <td id='tables9' class="nine" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99'; player_turn(); asasa=9"></td>
    </tr>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      asasa = 0;

      function player_turn() {

        if (document.getElementById('tables1').className == 'one' & asasa == 1) {
          document.getElementById('tables1').className = 'none'

          alert("Bot turn")
        } else if (document.getElementById('tables2').className == 'two' && asasa == 2) {
          document.getElementById('tables2').className = 'none'

          alert("Bot turn")
        } else if (document.getElementById('tables3').className == 'three' && asasa == 3) {
          document.getElementById('tables3').className = 'none'

          alert("Bot turn")
        } else if (document.getElementById('tables4').className == 'four' && asasa == 4) {
          document.getElementById('tables4').className = 'none'

          alert("Bot turn")
        }

        if (document.getElementById('tables5').className == 'five' && asasa == 5) {
          document.getElementById('tables5').className = 'none'

          alert("Bot turn")
        }

        if (document.getElementById('tables6').className == 'six' && asasa == 6) {
          document.getElementById('tables6').className = 'none'

          alert("Bot turn")
        }

        if (document.getElementById('tables7').className == 'seven' && asasa == 7) {
          document.getElementById('tables7').className = 'none'

          alert("Bot turn")
        }

        if (document.getElementById('tables8').className == 'eight' && asasa == 8) {
          document.getElementById('tables8').className = 'none'

          alert("Bot turn")
        }

        if (document.getElementById('tables9').className == 'nine' && asasa == 9) {
          document.getElementById('tables9').className = 'none'

          alert("Bot turn")
        }
      }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Функция должна срабатывать при первом нажатии а не при втором.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте местами `player_turn();` и `asasa=...` во всех `onclick`.